# url routing with asp.net with 2 or more dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

i have a problem with url routing in asp.net webform.
i define :

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Parameters", "{CenterShop}/ ", "~/Default.aspx");
```

in RegisterRoutes() function in Global.asax and it work very well.
but i need to have something like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Parameters", "{CenterShop}/{Shop}/{Lot}/", "~/Default.aspx");
```

to have more dynamic parameter in url (shop and Lot), it work if i have url like this:

```
http://website/LondenCenterShop/LockShop/xperia Z1
```

but if one of this parameter will be null i have error on my page, when i have url like:

```
http://website.com/LondenCenterShop
```

i want to show list of shops that there in this CenterShop but i cant use this url, please hellp me to solve the problem.

thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it work already how you suggested? I am using MVC and there it does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sove it by adding tow more routes so my registerroutes() function is:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Parameters", "{CenterShop}/{Shop}/{Lot}", "~/Default.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Parameters1", "{CenterShop}/{Shop}/", "~/Default.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Parameters2", "{CenterShop}/", "~/Default.aspx");
```

and it work very well!